# Difference between Slim Alpine and regular tag for Solr Docker file

Tags: docker, solr, alpine-linux

I am new to Docker, and trying to use Solr on Docker.

I see there are many tags for the same version of Solr here https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/

What is difference between

7.6.0, 7.6.0-alpine or 7.6.0-slim ?

Which is better in production environment and for better out of box performance?

Comment: Primary advantage with the alpine distribution would be the image size (comparatively smaller) and yes, it is adopted well enough already. Slim (jesse) follows alpine.

Comment: get it. thanks. Still not sure about difference in slim vs alpine

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Solr 7 is 4 years old and has been EOL for years already, full of known vulnerabilities, so please use a current version of Solr, like 9.5.0.

Back in the 7.6 days the `-slim` suffix meant that you will get a `-slim` variant of the upstream openjdk and Debian images, with less tooling included and using less storage. Similarly the `-alpine` suffix means it does not use Debian but the Alpine linux distribution.

Since then lots has happened. The current version 9.x images have only two image variants, the "full" and a `-slim`. The full variant uses openjdk/Debian image that is already optimized, so no need for another tag. Now days the `-slim` suffix has a completely different meaning. It has nothing to do with upstream Linux distribution, but what Solr components will be included. Quoting [Solr's Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/solr?tab=tags):

> `solr:<version>-slim`:
> This image does not contain the common packages contained in the default tag and only contains the minimal packages needed to run solr. Unless you are working in an environment where only the solr image will be deployed and you have space constraints, we highly recommend using the default image of this repository.

Answer (score 0):

Alpine is the minimal version in terms of image size, so it would be more performant.

Comment: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/benchmarking-debian-vs-alpine-as-a-base-docker-image

Answer (score 0):

The full and slim Solr images correspond to the two binary distributions of Solr. The difference between full and slim:

`solr:7.6.0` - This is the defacto image. If you are unsure about what your needs are, you probably want to use this one. It is designed to be used both as a throw away container (mount your source code and start the container to start your app), as well as the base to build other images off of.(e.g. the prometheus-exporter).

`solr:7.6.0-slim` - This image does not contain the common packages contained in the default tag and only contains the minimal packages needed to run solr. Unless you are working in an environment where only the solr image will be deployed and you have space constraints, we highly recommend using the default image of this repository.

References:

https://hub.docker.com/_/solr

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It would have been correct for the current `9.x.x` images, but back with `7.x.x` the `-slim` suffix had a different use. Please see my answer above for explanation.